# C++ String Compare Returns 0 but Boolean returns false

Tags: c++, string, compare

I want to compare two strings to see if they are the same, not equal, greater, less, etc. I have the following code:

```
std::string _record = "adam";
std::string query = "adam";
int value = _record.compare(query);
return value == 0;
```

What is being returned is `false`. Using `cout` I notice that `value` returns an `int` that is zero. However, when I compare `value` to zero, it returns 1 (false).

Why does this happen?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce.](http://ideone.com/iSnVlE) -- Edit: Er, wait a minute. 1 is not false.

Comment: Why not simply `return _record == query;` if you don't care about less or greater?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Using `cout` I notice that value returns an `int` that is zero. However, when I compare value to zero, it returns `1` (`false`).

That is correct, except for the last bit: `bool(1)` is `true`, not `false`.

In other words, `0` does in fact equal `0`.

P.S. You can rewrite your function to `return _record == query`.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing 0 to 0 and getting a TRUE (1) back because 0 is equal to 0